# Java script is not loading with express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, kendo-ui

I'm trying to create a simple tree using Kendo's TreeView.

The HTML code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="kendo.default.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.data.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.treeview.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
//To check if the scripts are loading
var len = $('script').filter(function () {
                return ($(this).attr('src') == 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js');
            }).length;

            //if there are no scripts that match, the load it
            if (len === 0) {
                $.getScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js');
                console.log("jquery not loading");
            }
            else
                console.log("jquery loading");
```

//

```
            var len = $('script').filter(function () {
                return ($(this).attr('src') == 'http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.data.min.js');
            }).length;

            //if there are no scripts that match, the load it
            if (len === 0) {
                $.getScript('http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.data.min.js');
                console.log("treeview kendo not loading");
            }
            else
                console.log("treeview kendo loading");


            len = $('script').filter(function () {
                return ($(this).attr('src') == 'http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.core.min.js');
            }).length;

            //if there are no scripts that match, the load it
            if (len === 0) {
                $.getScript('http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.core.min.js');
                console.log("core kendo not loading");
            }
            else
                console.log("core kendo loading");

            len = $('script').filter(function () {
                return ($(this).attr('src') == 'http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.treeview.min.js');
            }).length;

            //if there are no scripts that match, the load it
            if (len === 0) {
                $.getScript('http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.treeview.min.js');
                console.log("data kendo not loading");
            }
            else
                console.log("data kendo loading");



var inlineDefault = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: [
        { text: "Furniture", items: [
            { text: "Tables & Chairs" },
            { text: "Sofas" },
            { text: "Occasional Furniture" }
        ] },
            { text: "Decor", items: [
            { text: "Bed Linen" },
            { text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
            { text: "Carpets" }
        ] }
    ]
});
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: inlineDefault
});
</script>
<div id="example">

<div class="demo-section k-content">
<h4>Inline data</h4>
<div id="treeview"></div>
</div>

<style>
.box .k-textbox {
width: 100px;
}
</style>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This HTML page is served by a Node js which is as below:

```
var nano = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require ('fs');
var bp = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bp.urlencoded({extended: false});

app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3001);

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
});

app.get('/a',function(req,res){
    res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname+"/a.html");
});

app.get('/kendo.common.min.css',function(req,res){
    res.setHeader('content-type','text/css');
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/kendo.common.min.css");
});

app.get('/kendo.default.min.css',function(req,res){
    res.setHeader('content-type','text/css');
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/kendo.default.min.css");
});

app.get('/kendo.default.mobile.min.css',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/images/kendoui.woff");
});


app.get('/images/kendoui.woff?v=1.1 ',function(req,res){
    res.setHeader('content-type','text/css');
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/kendo.default.mobile.min.css");
});

app.get('/kendo.core.min.js',function(req,res){
    res.setHeader('content-type','text/javascript');
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/kendo.core.min.js');
});

app.get('/kendo.treeview.min.js',function(req,res){
    res.setHeader('content-type','text/javascript');
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/kendo.treeview.min.js');
});

app.get('/kendo.data.min.js',function(req,res){
    res.setHeader('content-type','text/javascript');
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/kendo.data.min.js');
});

app.listen (app.get( 'port' ), function (){
console.log ('Express started on http://localhost:' +
app.get ('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.' );
});
```

So this example of the HTML code is an example I found [here](http://%20%3Ca%20href%20=%20%22http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/local-data-binding%22%3E). The only difference here is that the html and kendo js files are loading from my nodeJs server. And checking if the javascripts are loading, I did a test I found here on StackOverflow. Everything but the TreeView is loading. Chrome's developer tools isn't throwing any error and neither is Node. Someone please explain why this isn't loading.

Thanking you in advance.

EDIT: So before going with @LuizFernandodaSilva 's comment, when I ran, the console in Chrome looks like this. I assumed from this that the scripts are loading. 
[image]
Going with his comment, I switched to CDNs for the javascript and the css and the console shows the exact same as above but does not load the tree.

Comment: Why are you loading the javascript in the frontend and in the nodejs api? Is it a frontend js or a node code? 

If it is a frontend code, maybe you just need to check de path to the scripts (probably ./kendo... instead kendo...). Otherwise, it can be server as a file, but I think isn't necessary, as you can just acess the script by url.

Also, did you look to the console to developer tools? Usually it gives tips. For example, if is a path problem, probably the console will log a not found error.

Comment: Just one more observation: if it is just a frontend script, you can use the CDN code instead of the script file, in the same way you are using the jquery plugin.

Comment: @LuizFernandodaSilva It is a frontend script so I switched to CDNs. It shows that the script is loading in the console but the tree isn't building. Please take a look at the screenshot I edited in.

Comment: Thanks @LuizFernandodaSilva for taking the time to help. I tried running the exact same script that worked when I ran locally and put it in nodeJs and worked which I realised had no difference with the one I posted. It works now. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went back to the example and copied the code provided there (could not find the difference between this and the provided example). Re-ran it and it worked.